# Python program to map a series of chemical reactions with unique nodes only appearing once

Tags: python, networkx

I have written a program in python to compose a map of a chemistry an example of which is the below text in the format: reactants > products.

```
H2 > H2
H2 > H2
H2 > H2*
H2 > H2*
H2 > H + H
H2 > H2^
H2 > H* + H
H2 > H + H
H2^ > H2^
H2^ > H^ + H
H2^ > H + H
H3^ > H3^
H3^ > H^ + H2
H3^ > H + H2
H > H
H > H*
H > H^
H^ > H^
H^ > H
H + H2^ > H2 + H^
H2 + H2^ > H + H3^
CF4 > CF4
CF4 > F- + CF3
```

I want my program to create nodes on the map for every species in the chemistry and draw pathways between reactants and products with one species appearing only once on the map and the map having lines to represent a reaction from each reactant in the reaction to each product in the reaction.

I have written the below code however this code is simply taking each reaction and drawing it on the map and it is not connecting them and I am unsure how best to proceed linking up the common species in the reactions.

```
import os
import sys
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import copy

try:
data = sys.argv[1]
except IndexError:
    print('Insert filename')
    sys.exit(1)

def parse_line(line):
    new=line.split('>')
    reactants=new[0].split('+')
    products=new[1].split('+')
    return reactants,products



all_edges=[]
edge_labels={}
all_reactants=[]
all_products=[]

with open(data) as fi:
    for line in fi.readlines():
        line = line.strip()
        if not line or line[0] in '#%!':
        # skip blank and comment lines
            continue
        reactants,products = parse_line(line)

        for i in np.arange(len(reactants)):
            other_reactants=copy.copy(reactants)
            other_reactants.remove(reactants[i])
            other_reactants=', '.join(other_reactants)
            for j in np.arange(len(products)):
                edge=(reactants[i],products[j])
                all_edges.append(edge)
                edge_labels[edge]=other_reactants



gr=nx.DiGraph()

gr.add_edges_from(all_edges)

pos=nx.random_layout(gr)

nx.draw_networkx_nodes(gr,pos,node_size=2000,node_shape='o',node_color='0.75',alpha=10)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(gr,pos, width=0.05,edge_color='b')

nx.draw_networkx_labels(gr, pos,font_size=12, font_color='k', font_weight='normal', alpha=1.0, ax=None)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(gr,pos,edge_labels=edge_labels, label_pos=0.01, ax=None, rotate=False)
plt.show()
```

Could anyone advise me on the best way to proceed with this, I need a function that will identify the common species in reactants and products in all reactions and create a single node for each unique species and create one line from each reactant to each product for each reaction.

Any help would be hugely appreciated

Thank you very much

Comment: Coming from chemical engineering background, the text is still quite difficult to interpret what you want; is there a way you can generalise this without chemical terminology? I've never used `networkx` so I can't meet you half way, but I think this would be very hard to answer in its current state.

Comment: In essence I think you're asking for something like a _directed graph_ in which everything left of `>` points to all things it's associated with on the right of `>`? But what does `H2 > H2` even mean, and why is it there twice? Also, you consider the (what I think to be) radical `H*` a distinct species to `H`? I think these questions might be a barrier to an answer... for my own curiosity, what is `^`?

Comment: Thank you very much for the interest and elucidating questions. I will answer you second question first simply because I will prepare some .pngs for your second question. There are two types of reactants "electron collision reactions" and "heave particle reactions". In the electron collision reactions the electrons are not printed as they are not to appear on the chemistry map. So H2 > H2 is actually e + H2 > e + H2 which is called an elastic reaction. These reactions shouldn't appear on the map but I can put in a bit of code to get rid of them. H* is a "metastable" of H it is different.

Comment: And H^ just means H+, the ion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the problems you seem to be having is that you're not stripping the whitespace from around the reactants/products you parse out of the "qstrings" of reactions. This means that e.g. `' H2'` and `'H2 '` are treated as different species and so get distinct nodes in your graph.

You probably want to handle this with something like:

```
reactants = [s.strip() for s in new[0].split('+')]
products = [s.strip() for s in new[1].split('+')]
```

in your `parse_line` function.